# How to retrieve a queued task with task_name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am building a Python application that works with taskqueue in the following flow

1. Add a pull task to taskqueue by calling `taskqueue.add()`
2. Lease the same task by calling `taskqueue.lease_tasks()`
3. After some time, we may want to shorten the lease time by calling `taskqueue.modify_task_lease()`

The problem is, those 3 steps happen in different web sessions. At step 3, the `modify_task_lease()` function need a task instance as argument, while I only have task_name in hand, which is passed from step 2 with web hooks.

So is there any way to retrieve a task with its name?

In the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue#google.appengine.api.taskqueue.Queue.modify_task_lease), I found `delete_tasks_by_name()`, but there is no `modify_task_lease_by_name()`, which is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`delete_tasks_by_name()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue#Queue.delete_tasks_by_name) is just a wrapper around [`delete_tasks_by_name_async()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue#Queue.delete_tasks_by_name_async), which is implemented as

```
if isinstance(task_name, str):
  return self.delete_tasks_async(Task(name=task_name), rpc)
else:
  tasks = [Task(name=name) for name in task_name]
  return self.delete_tasks_async(tasks, rpc)
```

So I guess you could similarly use the [`Task()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue#Task) constructor to obtain the task instance needed by [`modify_task_lease()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue#Queue.modify_task_lease):

```
modify_task_lease(Task(name=your_task_name), lease_seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach but always get TaskLeaseExpiredError exception. It seems the modify_task_lease() function only utilizes two properties of task instance: name and _eta_usec. I also tried to build Task instance with different eta values (soon after now, long after now, etc.), yet can't make it work correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. The backend server is checking the identity of task.eta and request.eta. So I need to make sure the new dummy task has the same eta as the one that I want to modify. What I need to do is to pass around the Task.eta property together with Task.name. Then, when to modify lease time, I can build a dummy task with those two properties. Thank you for suggestion. It helped!